# How do I create a dynamic array with real numbers?

Tags: c++, arrays, dynamic

I know the syntax for dynamic arrays with integers, but when I try to create a dynamic array that stores double values, it gives me an error message. (`error: expression in new-declarator must have integral or enumeration type`)

```
ifstream f("date.in");
ofstream g("date.out");
double n;
f >> n;
double* v = new double[n];

for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
    f >> v[i];
```

I usually do

```
int n;
f >> n;
int* v = new int[n];
```

and it works.

Comment: vector is a better way

Comment: so instead of that use v[1000] declared as a double?

Comment: Even though the array _stores_ `double`s, the _number of elements it stores_ is still a discrete value. `double n;` should be `int n;` or `size_t n;` or similar.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As the error message suggests, `double n;` cannot be used as the number of elements, which must be an integer. It should be `int n;`.

Comment: yeah I didn't really think this through, did I? :))

Answer (score 2):

You could also use std::vector:

```
int main()
{
  ifstream f("date.in");
  ofstream g("date.out");
  
  size_t fSize;
  f >> fSize;
  std::vector<double> v(fSize);

  for(size_t i=0; i<n && f.good(); i++) f >> v[i];
}
```